# ASP.NET - Environment.NewLine wrap li tag

Tags: asp.net

I have this line of code:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.features.feature.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br /><br />"))
```

instead of doing 
 I would like to wrap the text around in an li tag...how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
@foreach(string s in Model.features.feature.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine } , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    <li> @s </li>
}
</ul>
```